# Not able to understand this piece of code regarding java Optional

Tags: java, option-type

We can use map on Optional, which as per my understand returns value of the method call on the object wrapped by the Optional. Correct me if I am wrong here!!.

So does the map returns the value resulting from the method call inside it as it is, or it returns the value wrapped inside an Optional?

So if I have an

```
Optional<T> optOfTypeT = Optional.ofNullable(objOfTypeT);
```

then what would be the return type of

```
optTypeT.map(t -> t.someOperationOnT());
```

Will the return type be of type  `T`,  or  `Optional<T>` ?

Suppose we have a person class.

```
class Person{
       String name;

       Person(String name){
         this.name = name;
       }

       public String getName(){
          return this.name;
       } 
   }

    // Now the main class.

  class Main {
       Optional<Person> oPerson = Optional.nullable( personService.getPerson());
       Optional<String> oName = oPerson.map(p -> p.getName()); // I will get a String value wrapped in the Optional.

       System.out.println("It will not print a name" + oName);

       String name = oPerson.map(person -> person.getName()).orElse("anonymous");// I will get a String in return for this call, not an Optional object in return.     

       System.out.println("Name will be printed -->" + name);
   }
```

I mean why should we get an Optional wrapped object in the first call but a string in the second?

What is that chaining orElse after the map operation we get a naked unwrapped value and without it map returns a Optional wrapped object?

Is there any gap in my understanding, please throw some light here!!

Comment: The map returns an Optional in both cases. In the second case there's also an orElse.

Comment: Look at the return types of `map` and `orElse`. Did you miss the word `orElse`?

Comment: orElse will just return the default value in case the reference wrapped by Optional will does not point to an object.

Comment: @JohnDoe "orElse" is simply named poorly. Its logic would be described better by "getOrElseGet(...)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment "orElse" is named a bit poorly. Its inner logic would be better described by something like "getOrElseGet(...)" as it implicitly tries to return the value contained in the optional.

See `java.util.Optional#orElse`:

```
public T orElse(T other) {
    return value != null ? value : other;
}
```

Comment: You mean to say orElse() is doing a get tacitly!!.   i.e.  Optional.get() is being done by the orElse() without specifying so.

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, exactly.

Comment: The OP's comment does a better job than the actual answer, could you include an actual explanation?

Comment: Very Good explanation @MttDiMu, you have clarified this to so many others who would have same confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Java docs for the method `map(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper)`

> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and
>   if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result.

By design `Optional` signifies that a value might or might not be present. In case it's not, then the `map()` method has no other choice but not to run the input lambda and return an `Optional.empty()`